# DOS filename escaping for use with *nix commands

Tags: scripting, shell, dos

I want to escape a DOS filename so I can use it with sed. I have a DOS batch file something like this:

```
set FILENAME=%~f1

sed 's/Some Pattern/%FILENAME%/' inputfile
```

(Note: `%~f1` - expands `%1` to a Fully qualified path name - `C:\utils\MyFile.txt`)

I found that the backslashes in `%FILENAME%` are just escaping the next letter.

How can I double them up so that they are escaped?

(I have cygwin installed so feel free to use any other *nix commands)

## Solution

Combining Jeremy and Alexandru Nedelcu's suggestions, and using | for the delimiter in the sed command I have

```
set FILENAME=%~f1
cygpath "s|Some Pattern|%FILENAME%|" >sedcmd.tmp
sed -f sedcmd.tmp inputfile
del /q sedcmd.tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.  It's messy because in BAT files you can't use set var=`cmd` like you can in unix.
The fact that echo doesn't understand quotes is also messy, and could lead to trouble if `Some Pattern` contains shell meta characters.

```
set FILENAME=%~f1
echo s/Some Pattern/%FILENAME%/ | sed -e "s/\\/\\\\/g" >sedcmd.tmp
sed -f sedcmd.tmp inputfile
del /q sedcmd.tmp
```

[Edited]: I am suprised that it didn't work for you.  I just tested it, and it worked on my machine.  I am using sed from http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils and using cmd.exe to run those commands in a bat file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try as alternative (from the command prompt) ...

```
> cygpath -m c:\some\path
c:/some/path
```

As you can guess, it converts backslashes to slashes.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandru & Jeremy, Thanks for your help. You both get upvotes

@Jeremy

Using your method I got the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 8:
>   unterminated `s' command

If you can edit your answer to make it work I'd accept it. (pasting my solution doesn't count)

**Update:** Ok, I tried it with UnixUtils and it worked. (For reference, the UnixUtils I downloaded was dated March 1, 2007, and uses GNU sed version 3.02, my Cygwin install has GNU sed version 4.1.5)